# Vuforia + Unity dynamic shapes & pattern recognition

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am pretty new to Vuforia/Unity and I cant seem to find the right starting point for my usecase:

I have a number of distinctive geometrical black and white patterns (stripes, cubes, crosses etc.) and these need to be recognised and a 3d shape should be displayed on top. So far I could just use Frame Markers or QRCodes etc.

BUT the size and especially the shape of the detected objects are going to differ and so should the displayed object above it. If the object is a circle, I want a column to show up above it. If the object is a triangle, a triangular object should appear above it. The pattern would then determine the color of these objects of different shape.

I am very puzzled on where to start looking.

Comment: Have you created VuMark for those shapes in your Vuforia->TargetManager page? If yes, those images should be rated 4-5 stars of augment-ability.

Comment: the patters have a 4-5 star rating in the targetmanager. but the shapes will be different everytime, so i cant a them to the targetmanager. that is the basic problem i am addressing here.

Comment: Then you need to do a kind of image processing before asking Vuforia to identify the images for you! For example, design an algorithm that divides an image into atomic basic shapes. Afterwards, let vuforia to identify each basic shape based on the pre-defined image targets. In other words you could do a kind of mix and match...

Comment: As I was looking at smart terrain, it seemed like that might be a solution. The difference in my example would be, that object identification would be based on a pattern and not a real 3D object. But I that is again a wild guess

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is in Vuforia if you use image targets( in your case stripes cubes crosses etc.) you have to specify the size using Target Manager page. So if you do not need to dynamically change the size you can try creating multiple image targets of same images with different sizes. These images have to have at least 4 star rating. Then in your script you can access these image targets by index or name and scale your object accordingly.

However, if you need to create these markers or codes dynamically you can use [User Defined Targets](User Defined Targets). This requires user to scan the marker using device camera. User Defined Targets have capabilities of Image targets except virtual buttons.

Comment: first option is the standard image target definition - i am aware of that, but it does not seem to work for my case. the second option seems to require a lot of user interaction/configuration. we might be looking at 10-20 objects. for the user to define all of these seems to time intense.

Comment: Does first case  not seem to work because your images get lower ratings? or something else?

Comment: my images have 4-5 star ratings. my question here is all about a virtually endless amount of differenz shapes that need to be detected. thats why option one is not working for me

Comment: Then you need an image recognition solution which i do not think Vuforia can offer